# angular js - try to overwrite an existing object parts with no success

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i building a monthly report for a customer via google analytics api, i built a factory function to handle the requests and everything, i get this json array from inside the factory function:

```
var months = {
            paid_traffic: [
                {plan: "", sales: ""},{plan: "", sales: ""},{plan: "", sales: ""},
                {plan: "", sales: ""},{plan: "", sales: ""},{plan: "", sales: ""},
                {plan: "", sales: ""},{plan: "", sales: ""},{plan: "", sales: ""},
                {plan: "", sales: ""},{plan: "", sales: ""},{plan: "", sales: ""}
            ],
```

each object inside the array represent a month plan and sales.
i get details from google analytics and fill the object with it, till here everything works just fine, later on i need to calculate the total traffic for each month (i have few more object looks like that represent different google segments).
i have a problem with getting the results i garbed before in from google, it's keep return the empty initialized object my code look like this:

```
 function calcTotalTraffic(){
        for(var i in months.paid_traffic){
            console.log(i,months.paid_traffic[i],months.paid_traffic);
        }
    }
```

my `console.log` looks like this from some wired reason:

```
0 Object {plan: "", sales: ""} [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

the last result (for the `console.log(months.paid_traffic)`) look like that when opened :

```
0: Object$$hashKey: "object:13"plan: ""sales: 99601__proto__: Object1: Object$$hashKey: "object:14"plan: ""sales: 93185__proto__: Object2: Object3: Object4: Object5: Object6: Object7: Object8: Object9: Object10: Object11: Object
```

as you can see from some reason it's return the original empty object.

any idea why it is happening??

p.s even if i manually months.paid_traffic[0] it'r return the same empty row..

thanks for the help, i appreciate it :)

Comment: really not a good practice to use `for/in` on arrays

Comment: no, i just want to grab the information returned from google for each query related to traffic stuff then calculate the total amount of the returned values for each month...

Comment: Not understanding what you expect. The log looks just as would be expected although not sure why you want to log the whole array on each iteration. Nothing in code shown would change anything in the data

Comment: i accept to get the current object that inside the array - as months.paid_traffic[i] but it's return the object that i defined at the beginning, without the results add into it

Comment: As charlietfl helpfully commented, there's nothing wrong with the `console.log()` output. Can you please clarify your problem and tell us about exactly what you want to do?

Comment: what results?... question seems to be incomplete. Please update exactly what your expectations are because it is very unclear. All we can see is raw data and nothing that would change that data

Comment: sorry, you right i didn't mentioned that the the result of the console.log(months.paid_traffic); is an array of full objects not empty, it's after i grab some info from google, is that clear it out mate? :)

Comment: just edited it...is it better now?